# Using strlen() with arrays instead of strings

Tags: php, arrays, compare, strlen

I want to use `strlen()` to compare the length of two arrays. If the length of one array is greater than the other, then do something.

Unfortunately, I noticed that `strlen()` only works with strings? **How can I make it work with arrays?**

My code:

```
    $array1 = array(
        'Hello World',
        'Hello World',
        'Hello World',
        'Hello World',
        'Hello World'
    );

    $array2 = array(
        'Hello World',
        'Hello World'
    );


if (strlen($array1) > strlen($array2)) {

    echo 'It works you fool!';

}
```

Comment: Use the count function. `if (count($array1) > count($array2)) {`

Comment: I am amazed you couldn't work this out for yourself.

Comment: or sizeof() if you came from C world :)

Comment: @Steve I lost my mind with strings and converted my code to arrays and just didn't think enough :)

Comment: @HenrikPetterson happens to the best of us, but usually a plain english google does the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make it work with arrays?

PHP manual for `strlen()`:

> strlen() returns NULL when executed on arrays, and an E_WARNING level error is emitted.

You can't really.

Is there some reason why you "want" to do this?
There is a perfectly good function to achieve what you want - `count()`:

> count — Count all elements in an array, or something in an object

```
if (strlen($array1) > strlen($array2))
  {
    echo 'It works you fool!';
  }
```

Don't try to work PHP functions to suit your needs in scenarios they are not designed for.
Especially when there is (almost always likely) a perfectly good function which already suits your needs.

Future changes could make your "hack" no longer work, and also using the correct function means you will likely benefit from PHP ensuring accuracy, stability, speed, etc etc.

Hacking around often causes headaches, even if not now, in the future.

Answer (score 3):

To get array length you should use `count()`.

```
if (count($array1) > count($array2)) {
    echo 'It works you fool!';
}
```

Comment: or [sizeof()](http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php), which is does the exact same thing

Comment: @sean9999 So what's the difference? Is any of them better to use in terms of performance?

Comment: No difference. sizeof() is simply an alias for count(). I use sizeof() because in my opinion, it is slightly more readable